# How to calculate the sum of dynamically column with jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel

I've been create a table row with jquery, the column id is the id of data that have been selected. How can i calculate the sum of 'total_price' column which the id is dynamically (based on data id) ?

[image]

here my jquery script

```
function getCorporateService(id){
    //get data and parsing to column
    $.get("{{ url('salesorder/service')}}/"+id, function(data){
        console.log(id);
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (index, element){

            $br = "<tr id='item'>";
            $br += "<td> <input class='input-small' type='text' id='order_identifier' name='order_identifier' readonly></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='service["+id+"]' name='service["+id+"]' value='"+element.service_name+"' readonly></td>";
            $br += "<td><select id='order_type["+id+"]' name='order_type["+id+"]'> <option> - </option> <option value='add'>Add</option> <option value='change'>Change</option> <option value='cancel'>Cancel</option> </select></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='select_plan["+id+"]' name='select_plan["+id+"]'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-mini' type='text' id='qty["+id+"]' name='qty["+id+"]' value='1' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='unit_price["+id+"]' name='unit_price["+id+"]' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><input class='input-small' type='text' id='total_price["+id+"]' name='total_price["+id+"]' onChange='getTotalPrice("+id+")'></td>";
            $br += "<td><textarea class='input-small' id='notes["+id+"]' name='notes["+id+"]'></textarea></td>";
            $br += "</tr>";

            $(".corporatesvc").append($br);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Calculate it when? And display it where?

Comment: what is the problem with the `onChange` inliner?

Comment: Define var totalPrice = 0; before each and then totalPrice += getTotalPrice("+id+");

Comment: Please update your code with the jQuery function that is called while selection rows/data id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question without adding a class to the fields, use the [starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) inside the getTotalPrice

```
function getTotalPrice() {
  var total = 0; 
  $("[id^='total_price']").each(function() { // or $(".total_price") if given a class
    var val = $(this).val();
    total += isNaN(val) || $.trim(val)=="" ? 0 : parseFloat(val); // or parseInt(val,10);
  });
  $("#total").text(total.toFixed(2)); // or (total) if an int
}
```

You should give each of the changeable inputs a classname and assign a handler - onkeyup for example and use delegation:

```
$(function() {
  $(".corporatesvc").on("keyup",".changeable",function() {
    if (this.id.indexOf("qty")==0 ) {
      // here you can update siblings
    }
    getTotalPrice();
  });
});
```

Comment: `$("[id^='total_price']")` and `$("[id='total_price']")` both are same, right?

Comment: No. `^=` is starts with. That will handle `id="total_price"`, `id="total_price_1"`, and `id="total_price_2"`

Answer (score 1):

Give class name to each text box.`Check this` [**Link**](https://jsfiddle.net/mhcq8mmk/) `i hope it helps you.`
HTML

```
<input class='input-small total_price' type='text' id='total_price_1' name='total_price_1'>
<input class='input-small total_price' type='text' id='total_price_2' name='total_price_2' >
<input class='input-small total_price' type='text' id='total_price_3' name='total_price_3' >
<p id="classname">
```

JS

```
$(".total_price").each(function () {  
  $(this).keyup(function () {
    var sum = 0; 
    $(".total_price").each(function () {
      if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
        sum += parseFloat(this.value);
      }
      $("#classname").html(sum);
    });  
  });
});
```

Comment: There will not be a keyup event on the total_price fields. You mean add a class to the fields and then you can sum the .total_price class which is only on the total_price fields